# Overseas income on UK work visa

Tags: working-visas

Which incomes can I receive while in the UK on a work visa? Visa rules don’t seem to allow work outside the main Uk job.

1. Passive income from rental
2. Income from foreign owned business
3. Salary from foreign employer